# node.js express promise router error handling wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to create an error handling wrapper to use with the promise router extension of express in nodejs.

For starters, I try to simply wrap the async handler function:

```
function error_catcher(f)
{
    return (async function (request, response) {
        await f(request, response);
    });
}

router.get("/bar", (error_catcher((async (request, response) => {
    throw (new Error("bar error"));
}))()));
```

However, when I run this, I get:

```
Error: Expected a callback function but got a [object Promise]
    at wrapHandler (/tmp/complete/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:10:15)
    at /tmp/complete/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:87:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.instanceToWrap.(anonymous function) [as get] (/tmp/complete/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:86:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/complete/server.js:361:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

So if anyone can point out my error and help me make the wrapper for the async function work, I should be able to add the exception catching and error handling on my own.

Comment: Have you tried using `f` function directly as a middleware?

Answer (score 1):

You need a middleware like this

```
const error_catcher = fn =>
  (request, response, next) => {
    Promise
      .resolve(fn(request, response, next))
      .catch(next);
};
```

you can use it like

```
router.get("/bar", error_catcher(async (request, response, next) => {
  return await next(new Error("bar error"));
}));
```